# A qr scannig Fragment appears but no scan occurs

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

A call from a Fragment calls the scanner which is in another Fragment.
I've been trying to incorporate a Zxing library for days now. I finally incorporated a code that opens the scanner Fragment. Once the scanning screan appears, nothing happens.

I tried various libraries that are found on the intentet. Also tried calling a scanner from the Fragment, when the scanner was in an Activity instead of a Fragmnet.

**ScannerFragment**

```
public class ScannerFragment extends Fragment {

    ScanResultReceiver resultCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            resultCallback = (ScanResultReceiver) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ScanResultReceiver");
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(ScannerFragment.this);

//        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
        integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
//        integrator.setResultDisplayDuration(0);
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        ScanResultReceiver parentActivity = (ScanResultReceiver) this.getActivity();

        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result
            String codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String codeFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            // send received data
            if (parentActivity != null) {
                parentActivity.scanResultData(codeFormat,codeContent);
            }
        }else{
            // send exception
            if (parentActivity != null) {
                String noResultErrorMsg = "No scan data received!";
                parentActivity.scanResultData(new NoScanResultException(noResultErrorMsg));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**ScanningResultReceiver**

```
public interface ScanResultReceiver {

    public void scanResultData(String codeFormat, String codeContent);

    public void scanResultData(NoScanResultException noScanData);
}
```

**MoviesListFragment**

```
public class MoviesListFragment extends Fragment implements ScanResultReceiver {

    private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

    Context context;

    MoviesAdapter moviesAdapter;
    RecyclerView moviesRV;

    FragmentManager fm;
    private FragmentTransaction ft;

    Button addBtn;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_movies2, container, false);

        Log.i(TAG,"In movieListFragment");

        context = getActivity();

        addBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.addBtnId);

        formatTxt = rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        contentTxt = rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

        Bundle listBundle = getArguments();
        if (listBundle != null) {

            ArrayList<Movie> moviesList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("moviesList");
            if (moviesList != null) {

                moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(context, fm);

                moviesRV = rootView.findViewById(R.id.moviesRVId);
                moviesRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                moviesRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
                moviesRV.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);

                moviesAdapter.attachMoviesList(moviesList);
            }
        }

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("Monitoring", "Going to ScannerFragment");

                Fragment ScannerFragment = new ScannerFragment();
                fm = getFragmentManager();
                if (fm != null) {
                    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                }
                ft.replace(R.id.fragments_container, ScannerFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null) // add to back stack
                .commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void scanResultData(String codeFormat, String codeContent){
        // display it on screen
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + codeFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + codeContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void scanResultData(NoScanResultException noScanData) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,noScanData.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }


}
```

**NoScanResultException**

```
public class NoScanResultException extends Exception {
    public NoScanResultException() {}
    public NoScanResultException(String msg) { super(msg); }
    public NoScanResultException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
    public NoScanResultException(String msg, Throwable cause) { super(msg, cause); }
}
```

Comment: Does the Scanner require that a particular permission be declared in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: I wonder if you debug in your Activity. onActivityResult() it might be hitting there on scan, but not the fragments implementation of it. You might need to call through to the fragments version inside of the activity one.

Comment: I use permissions.
I didn't know what to debug because there's no error. I'll try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the camera can make a big difference on if that library can read the barcode. We use that library, and have scanning issues on certain devices. Also certain barcodes are hard for it to read.

I think we use an older version of zxing but in our fragment we implement this callback and the scanner will trigger automatically on scan

Gradle verson:`implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'`

```
public ClassName implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup c, Bundle b) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan, null);

        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
        List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
        formats.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
        formats.add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
        mScannerView.setFormats(formats);
        contentContainer.addView(mScannerView, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        // handle the result
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

then if you need to resume scanning you can use:
`mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScanBarcodeFragment.this);`